# Complex mysql select query 7

Tags: mysql

For example i have the table and values:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `words` (
  `wd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `st_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

----------------------------
|    wd_id    |    st_id    |
----------------------------
|      2      |     4       |
----------------------------
|      5      |     4       |
----------------------------
|      7      |     8       |
----------------------------
|      2      |     8       |
----------------------------
|      7      |     9       |
----------------------------
|      2      |     10      |
----------------------------
|      5      |     10      |
----------------------------
```

wd_id is id of word 
 st_id is id of sentence

if i know id of two words. i want to get list of sentences which have this words.
for example this ids is 2 and 5 then  ANSWER will be 4 and 10.

In this table will be milions of rows. So i need write query carefully!!!

here is query which i wrote:

```
  SELECT st_id 
  FROM words
  WHERE wd_id = 5 AND st_id IN (
      SELECT st_id
      FROM words
      WHERE wd_id = 2
    )
```

CAN SOMEONE WRITE BETTER QUERY? OR QUERY WHICH WILL WORK for N WORDS? 
AND IF I ADD INDEXES FOR wd_id AND st_id COLUMNS this query will be faster yes?
AND WHAT TYPE OF INDEXES WILL BE GOOD?

Comment: Yes, you should add indexes to any fields you are using in your 'WHERE' condition. You won't notice a speed increase until the data set begins to grow as the cost of doing a full table scan is low while the number of records is small.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  st_id
FROM    words
WHERE   wd_ID IN (2, 5)
GROUP   BY st_id
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT wd_ID) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f338/1)

If `wd_ID` is unique for every `st_id`, you don't need to have `DISTINCT` in the having clause,

```
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

You can read more on this link,

- [SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Thank you! 
Can you exlpain this part HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT wd_ID) = 2
and how will be query for N words?

Comment: The query is filtering all `st_id` which has *either* `5` or `2` value of `wd_ID`. Then it groups the `st_id` and filtering only records which has a value of `2`, *result of aggregating the rows*, since you are searching for two values in `st_id`. [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f338/9)

Comment: AND WHAT ABOUT for N WORDS? Can you give me idea?